# fail to write to file with Python

Tags: python, file

I wrote some python code to pull a table from web and save it to a file. In the interactive mode I am able to test my code and save the data to file. However when I run the file with command line, it didn't give andy error message but the file is empty.

Here is a section of my code. I run 2.7.9 under windows

```
    rows=soup.tbody.findAll('tr')
outf=open('.\data\dec','w')
for tr in rows:
    cols=tr.findAll('td')
    out='*'.join([c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in cols])
    outf.write(out+'\n')

    outf.close
    browser.close()
```

Comment: `outf.close` should be `outf.close()`.

Comment: rows may be empty as well ...

Comment: Thanks. outf.close should be outf.close(), but this doesn't affect the result. I found that I need to put a pause (seelp) in the code and wait for the result. That's why when I use interactive mode, I can get the file correctly (copy the command one by one so there is enough time for the result to return). If run it in command line, without sleep, the result table is not ready yet. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue comes from your:

1. closing of outf INSIDE your `for` loop;
2. misuse of `.close()` (you only have `.close`); and
3. closing of `browser` INSIDE your `for` loop.

Your code **as posted** will only process one row, then close your file and browser!

You may find your code will work if rewritten like so:

```
rows=soup.tbody.findAll('tr')

with open('.\data\dec','w') as file_handle:
    for row in rows:
        cols = tr.findAll('td')
        file_handle.write('*'.join([c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in cols])+'\n')
browser.close()
```

**Note:** Using `with` automagically closes your file for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the indent, which look pretty weird. Please try

```
outf.close()
```

as you want to call the method, not referencing the method inside memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the following:

```
rows = soup.tbody.findAll('tr')
with open('.\data\dec', 'w') as file:
    for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.findAll('td')
    out = '*'.join([c.text.encode('utf-8') for c in cols])
    file.write('%s\n' % out)

browser.close()
```